# 'std::out_of_range' error in sending an image with sockets

Tags: python, opencv, sockets

I am using this code in Python to send an image with sockets (and OpenCV) to another computer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import cv2

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serversocket.bind(("XXX.XXX.X.XXX", 9999))

serversocket.listen(5)
print ('server started and listening')
while 1:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print ("connection found!")

    img = cv2.imread('testImage.jpeg')
    if (img.any()):
        clientsocket.sendall(img)
```

It works pretty well, but at some point it eventually shuts down, showing this error message:
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 140) > this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted**

I have searched in forums but I can't find an answer to my problem. Anyone can help me?

**EDIT:**

My socket client, that receives the image, is written in C#, and the code is the following:

```
 private void connectSocket()
        {
           receiveSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

           IPEndPoint hostIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("XXX.XXX.X.XXX"), 9999);

            receiveSocket.Connect(hostIpEndPoint);
            

        }


        private void btnImagem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (stream==0)
            {
                stream = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                stream = 0;
            }
           
            while (stream == 1)
            {
                connectSocket();
                wait(300);
                int dataSize;
                int y, x, t = 0;

                Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(160, 120);

                dataSize = 0;
                byte[] b = new byte[receiveSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
               
                dataSize = receiveSocket.Receive(b);
                if (dataSize > 0)
                {
                   
                    for (y = 0; y < 120; y++)
                    {
                        for (x = 0; x < 160; x++)
                        {
  
                            bmp2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(b[t + 2]), Convert.ToInt32(b[t + 1]), Convert.ToInt32(b[t])));
                            t = t + 3;

                        }
                    }
      
                }
                videoBox.Image = bmp2;

                receiveSocket.Close();
                 wait(10);
            }
            videoBox.Image = null;
        }

        public void wait(int milliseconds)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            if (milliseconds == 0 || milliseconds < 0) return;
            timer1.Interval = milliseconds;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Stop();
            };
            while (timer1.Enabled)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's a bug, but in the C++ part of your code. File a bug ticket with an [mcve] and a full backtrace.

Comment: How do you know it is in the C++ part? The only code I use in that language is the one in this repository: https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/raspberrypi_video , and the only thing I change is this line in the LeptonThread.cpp file, after line 269: **myImage.save("/home/pi/.../testImage.jpeg");**

Comment: `std::` is the prefix to specify things from the C++ standard library's namespace.

Comment: My other code that receives the image is in C#, do you think that could be it? Or this error is exclusively to C++?

Comment: I don't think C# uses anything similar.

Comment: Anyway, I edited the Issue, and inserted my C# code as well. So, now, that every code I used is shown here, what do you think is the bug?

Comment: It's not in your code. I guess it's somewhere in OpenCV, which is in C++ AFAIK. The problem is that it tries to use the 140th character from an empty string. It might be caused (or perhaps only triggered) by some input you provide, but it's hard to tell. For a start, extract a [mcve].

Comment: Right, so if I use another way to open the image instead of OpenCV, it should work, or not?

Comment: What is the point in your program that you refer to as _some point_, and why do you say _It works pretty well_ if it aborts?

Comment: What I mean is that it performs the intended task correctly, but sometimes the program shuts down with that error. This error occurs at random time intervals: it can abort after 5 seconds or after 2 minutes.